# How "props.children" works on a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I was working on the code of a practice for React, but I stopped because I have to make a navigation bar be shared among other pages

I found the next solution and it works but I don't know how exactly works; this is for a course project.

```
function Layout(props) {
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <Navbar />
      {props.children}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

I can't really know what really `{props.children}` does and how if Layout component start holding other components the Navbar component still appears

```
<Layout>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/badges" component={Badges}/>
    <Route exact path="/badges/new" component={BadgeNew} />
  </Switch>
</Layout>
```

What happens behind the scenes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`props.children` means that React will render whatever u put between `Layout` component.

For ex, if u put a div block between Layout components, `props.children` will be that div.

Comment: Oh wow, so basically it's like <router-outlet> of Angular, right?

Comment: sorry, I didn't use Angular, so I can't really compare it with react. But props.children basically let you pass in multiple components to your parent component without hardcoding those children inside the parent component, which increases scalability.

Comment: Awesome amigo, I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Every JSX code that you put inside the `Layout`-tag, will be placed in `children` property of `props`-object of the Layout Component.

```
<Layout>
  <div>this is a child</div>
  <AnotherReactComponentAsLayoutChild/>
</Layout>
```